# Smartface 4.3 Datepicker does not work

Tags: smartface.io

The following code was working with Smartface 4.2.4 but the same code crashes for Smartface 4.3. Did something change in the new version?

```
function Page1_ImageButton3_OnTouch(e){
    showDate();
}

function showDate(){ SMF.UI.showDatePicker({

        CurrentDate : new Date(), // date is given with JS date object
        mask : "YYYY-MM-DD",
        minDate:new Date("2000-01-01"),
        maxDate:new Date("2030-12-01"),
        showWorkingDate : true,
        onSelect : function(e) {
  alert("Working!")
     }
});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why did you set 2030 on maxDate?
Anyway, you have missed and write wrong some properties of datepicker object. You can try this it will work iOS and Android:

```
SMF.UI.showDatePicker({
    mask : "yyyy-MM-dd",
    currentDate : new Date(),
    minDate : new Date("2000-01-01"),
    maxDate : new Date("2030-12-01"),
    showWorkingDate : true,
    displayMode : 2,
    onSelect : function (e) {},
    onCancel : function (e) {}
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work! Infect yours and mine is the same code.

Comment: Device simulator works ok but if you publish the app crash Xcode output!

Comment: 2015-03-11 16:25:13.710 kursua[4665:60b] -[__NSCFString containsString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16b5a4e0
2015-03-11 16:25:13.714 kursua[4665:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString containsString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16b5a4e0'

Comment: *** First throw call stack:
(0x2fccef83 0x3a47fccf 0x2fcd2917 0x2fcd1203 0x2fc20768 0x277957 0x32521037 0x32687c45 0x32521037 0x32520fd7 0x32520fb1 0x3250c717 0x32520a2f 0x32520701 0x3251b6cb 0x324f08cd 0x324eef77 0x2fc9a20b 0x2fc996db 0x2fc97ecf 0x2fc02ebf 0x2fc02ca3 0x34b08663 0x3254f14d 0x9c373 0x3a98cab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: I dont know how to get crash report but xcode produces above fault during crash

Comment: Maybe, you cantact with Smartface Team. support@smartface.io